# SQL Insert select with dependency on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two database tables

> - customers
>
>   - id
>   - name
>   - email
>   - reseller_id
> - resellers
>
>   - id
>   - name
>   - email

I would like to migrate them to a new users table:

> - users
>
>   - id
>   - name
>   - email
>   - type (TYPE = 1 is Customer, TYPE 2 = Reseller)
> - customer_reseller
>
>   - customer_id
>   - reseller_id

I would like to do the migration via a mysql query. This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO customer_reseller (customer_id, reseller_id) 
    SELECT 
        (SELECT id FROM users WHERE type = 1) AS customer_id, 
        (SELECT ??) AS reseller_id'
    );
```

How would I get the reseller_id and make sure it is the one corresponding to  to the correct custiomer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Explanation*: What you are doing is changing the relationship between customers and resellers to be many-to-many instead of one-to-many using a junction table. In this case you will allow a customer to have more than one reseller associated.

---

You need your pre-migration data from `customers` to know which customer is associated to which reseller, so this would be a simple query from one table to migrate all associations.

```
INSERT INTO customer_reseller (customer_id, reseller_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT id, reseller_id
  FROM customers
```

Note the use of `DISTINCT` to only pick up unique pairs (if you didn't have it enforced by constraints before this is a good place to put it in).

Comment: The problem is that, by simultaneously migrating customers to users, where reseller_id does not exist, the customer_id changes, so I can't use this way

Comment: You are not doing simultaneous migration. You are most likely executing script in order which is different. You just need to store association between old customer id and new customer id :-) You have control over it.

Comment: Does it mean that you store resellers in customers table? Please attach sample data showing your issue.

Comment: You're right, I can work like this wit a temp table. Thanks!